# How to use a variable outside the promise

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

So i have a authorization token in my ionic storage and i have to pass it throught http request but i cant seem to get the value out of the storage.get.then promise.

```
  getProducts(){
    let headers = new Headers(); 
    this.token= this.storage.get('Authorization').then((value)=>{
       this.token= value;
      return this.token; 
     });
     headers.append("Authorization",this.token);

    return this.http.get('https://vjtest.cobold.xyz/vapi/public/api/products',{headers: headers})
      .map(res=> res.json());

  }
```

Comment: @wolverine if i place the http.get inside i will get error at the subscribe part since http.get return will not return the product value from getProduct //Sorry its bad to put into words

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since promises are asynchronous, you have to wait for the response and then call the second request.

```
getProducts(){
     return this.storage.get('Authorization').then((value)=>{
       this.token= value;
       return this.sendReq(this.token)
     });
}

sendReq(token){
      let headers = new Headers();       
      headers.append("Authorization",token);
      return this.http.get('https://vjtest.cobold.xyz/vapi/public/api/products',{headers: headers})
      .map(res=> res.json());
}
```

Comment: Thank you ,your code makes sense though I am experiencing this error any idea why? "Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Promise<Observable<any>>"

Comment: you have to subscribe to the HTTP get a request in order to access the request.

Answer (score 0):

You either return the http request (which will be an Observable) and subscribe to your function, 
or you manipulate it after subscribing to the request itself :

```
this.http
.get('https://vjtest.cobold.xyz/vapi/public/api/products',{headers: headers})
.subscribe(data => {
  //manipulate what the request returned here
});
```

Comment: I am not manipulating the data , i am simply returning it . I am trying to fetch the token from ionic storage and putting it into the header for authentication.

Comment: Then you dont have to map it. Its up to whoever called it to map it and manipulate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) function.

```
getToken() {
   return this.storage.get('Authorization');
}

async getProducts(){
  this.token = await getToken();
  let headers = new Headers(); 
  headers.append("Authorization",this.token);
  return his.http.get('https://vjtest.cobold.xyz/vapi/public/api/products',headers: headers}).map(res=> res.json());

}
```

Comment: @MayankSingh try removing the function keyword, refer the updated answer